# Custom validation Angular 6 - at least one textarea filled

Tags: angular, validation

When I click submit, and none of the textarea is completed, I must see an error. When at least one is filled - I want to render submit action? How can I do it in best way?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfbram?file=src/app/app.component.htmlhttps://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vz8g7d

Comment: Start using reactive forms for starters.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Template Driven Approach:**

```
 <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let t of textarea; let in=index">
          <textarea  class="form-control"
                    rows="5" [(ngModel)]="textarea[in].value" 
                    [name]="'something' + in" 
                    placeholder="Type..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button (click)="add()">Add input</button>
<button  type="submit" >Submit</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Component:**
Iterate through the object to know whether it's empty or not. Listen to `valueChanges` event on form Group and take action based on it.

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('form') myForm: NgForm;
  textarea: { value: string }[];
  isError: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.textarea = [{ value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }];

  }

  add() {
    this.textarea.push({ value: '' });
  }

  isEmpty(obj): boolean {
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key].length) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.isError = false;
    })
  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    if (this.isEmpty(form)) {
      this.isError = true;
    } else {
      this.isError = false;
    }
  }
}
```

[`Forked StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vje7du)

Comment: @emka26 Perhaps  you looking for this:)

Comment: You should notify him on his question directly, one doesn't get notifications unless he is the OP or has commented

Comment: @trichetriche thanx mate I was unaware of it

Comment: Ok @Vikas, great, it's almost what I need. Now only one thing: I need have an error when isEmpty == true, so I modify onSubmit function and display this error. But problem is, when I add text to textarea after display error, I want to hide this error immediately (non after next clixk submit but after type text). How can i do it? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etq9hs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @emka26 Have a look at the updated ans and stackblitz.

Comment: @emka26 Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Following your pattern you can use `Array.every`:

```
allEmpty() {
  return this.textarea.every(t => t.value === '')
}

<button [disabled]="allEmpty()">Submit</button>
```

EDIT:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit($event)">Submit</button>

<span *ngIf="allEmpty() && clicked">
  error
</span>

clicked = false;
allEmpty() {
  return this.textarea.every(t => t.value === '')
}

onSubmit(e) {
  this.clicked = true;
  if (this.allEmpty()) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok @HiWorld, but I don't want to disabled button, only do not perform the submit action and display the error.

Comment: edited, though the way you work on form is not the Angular way. I reccomend to read on template driven forms, o reactive driven form

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using plain old Javascript, here is the Angular way : a custom validation function at form group level.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1zffj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
function atLeastOneTextarea(): ValidatorFn {
  return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
    const hasAtLeastOneValue = Object.keys(group.value).some(key => !!group.value[key]);

    return !hasAtLeastOneValue && { 'atLeastOne': true } || null;
  };
}
```

The validator will test if the value of the form has at least one truthy value. If there isn't, it will show the error.

I switched to reactive forms because for validation, it is way better for understanding how it works when you're a beginner. Feel free to change it to your needs for template driven forms, or keeep it as is.

Comment: @Vikas, I would like you to to not edit my answer. You "corrected" perfectly valid English and appended wrong things to my answer. Next time, please restrain yourself from doing so.

Comment: Thanks, how this code will look like in template driven forms? And I don't want to have disabled submit button, but display error after click submit and not render submit action if error exist.

Comment: you can change the `*ngIf` of the button, I simply used it to check if my validator was working (faster than writing the error !). For the template driven form, you can check [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms), which will explain it better than I will !

Comment: @trichetriche "corrected" perfectly valid English I may agree but *appended wrong things to my answer*  what was wrong in my edit ?? ain't Reactive forms and model driven approach same?

Comment: Model driven doesn't mean anything, it can apply to both reactive and template driven !